# Autoit Badly formated variable or macro

Tags: autoit

I am new to Autoit and tried to do this:

```
Local $stest = "C:\Program Files (x86)\test\test.exe";
Local $sPath;

runS($stest);

Func runS(String $sPath) {

   this.$sPath = $sPath;

   If FileExists($stest) {
      Run($stest , "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
   }

}
```

And get this error:

> (6) : ==> Badly formated variable or macro.:

I am just trying to write a parameter as a path in the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No lines in AutoIt end with a ";". The ";" is used for commenting in
  AutoIt.
- If statements must have a “then” statement.
- Nothing in AutoIt is opened or closed with the curly braces “{}”.
- Most statements are closed with semantic words like EndIf, EndFunc and
  Wend.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
;$g_sTest is global variable because it is being declared outside of a function. 
Global $g_sTest = "C:\Program Files (x86)\test\test.exe"

runS($stest)

;$sPath will be a local variable because it is being declared inside of the fuction.
Func runS($sPath)
   If FileExists($sPath) Then
      Run($sPath, "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
   EndIf
EndFunc
```